# Install vulkan driver for fglrx AMD graphics

Tags: 14.04, fglrx, amd-graphics, vulkan

Does anyone know how to install `vulkan` for `fglrx` or Radeon (open source) driver in Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fglrx is no more maintained, this driver is abandoned, so it never (I think) get any update. 
AMD only maintaining FirePro driver and embedded device but not for desktop/mobile.

For desktop/mobile GPU they preparing new closed source driver called AMD GPU-PRO with Vulkan support.
They also developing open source amdgpu but for they not add Vulkan support for it (but should coming in some time).

Also other open drivers like radeon or radeonSI not get Vulkan support. So only solution if you want have Vulkan is change driver to amd gpu-pro. Ofc if you have supported GPU. Here you have supported gpu list:

http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Radeon-GPU-PRO-Linux-Beta-Driver%e2%80%93Release-Notes.aspx

Answer (score 0):

one of options is to go with open source drivers for ur card, as fglrx is previous closed source driver for amd, just de-install it,and go with open source drivers , then i recommend to add padoka repo.. so u will be on appropriate radeon,or  gallium or amd-gpu driver or and then to go what will depends of card model u have to install amd -gpu pro on top of those..
sure u can install vulkan in separate folder to build applications with it.
first read this as even with newest vulkan SDK ubuntu 14.04 is supported!(and newer,16.04 and so on...) https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/sdk/1.0.37.0/linux/getting_started.html
then download from same page..
just one note if you download and install amd gpu driver from amd page it will install newest vulkan too..
so,basically it depends for what you need vulkan,to build apps,or to play ...and yes you do not need to de-install open source driver for your card if u plan to add on top of it =install amd gpu pro..as is just addition!
i was on gallium driver ,and i add on top of it amd gpu pro..
Its worth to clarify!
So even something not go by plan you will not be left without driver and with black screen in front of you,what is nice.
That means that amd closed source drivers are based on open source driver..and development of one will improve other,at least i see things like that..and maybe this will you need
http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/Install-LunarG-Vulkan-SDK.aspx